# How to report a problem in Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I have login issues at Facebook.

It sends the confirmation email at the wrong address.
My address is xyz@yahoo.es but it sends me the confirmation mail at xyz@yahhoo.com

That mail doesn't work for me and the mail does not arrive

I try to Report a Problem, I get to this page https://m.facebook.com/help/1126628984024935/?helpref=hc_fnav

And it says I have to chose option "Report a problem".

I do that and then I get to the same page

So how to report a problem?

Answer (score 1):

From [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help):

> [Report a Login Issue](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/357439354283890)
>
> If you're having trouble logging in or with your password, you've come to the right place. Please use this form to tell us about the issue you're experiencing.